# при интале библиотеки UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 17: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, pycharm, install, decode

Господа, добрый день! Уже не знаю что делать, пытаясь установить библиотеки в терминале PyCharm ловлю следующее:

```
(venv) C:\Users\Иван\PycharmProjects\SeleniumEducation>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-21.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.1.1
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Иван\PycharmProjects\SeleniumEducation\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Иван\PycharmProjects\SeleniumEducation\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 185, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Иван\PycharmProjects\SeleniumEducation\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 398, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
  File "C:\Users\Иван\PycharmProjects\SeleniumEducation\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 63, in install_given_reqs
    uninstalled_pathset = requirement.uninstall(
  File "C:\Users\Иван\PycharmProjects\SeleniumEducation\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 675, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset = UninstallPathSet.from_dist(dist)
  File "C:\Users\Иван\PycharmProjects\SeleniumEducation\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 456, in from_dist
    if not dist_is_local(dist):
  File "C:\Users\Иван\PycharmProjects\SeleniumEducation\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 383, in dist_is_local
    return is_local(dist_location(dist))
  File "C:\Users\Иван\PycharmProjects\SeleniumEducation\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 529, in dist_location
    egg_link = egg_link_path(dist)
  File "C:\Users\Иван\PycharmProjects\SeleniumEducation\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 505, in egg_link_path
    if not virtualenv_no_global() and user_site:
  File "C:\Users\Иван\PycharmProjects\SeleniumEducation\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\virtualenv.py", line 111, in virtualenv_no_global
    return _no_global_under_venv()
  File "C:\Users\Иван\PycharmProjects\SeleniumEducation\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\virtualenv.py", line 72, in _no_global_under_venv
    cfg_lines = _get_pyvenv_cfg_lines()
  File "C:\Users\Иван\PycharmProjects\SeleniumEducation\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\virtualenv.py", line 55, in _get_pyvenv_cfg_lines
    return f.read().splitlines()  # avoids trailing newlines
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 17: character maps to <undefined>
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 21.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\Иван\PycharmProjects\SeleniumEducation\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

такое происходит при любой попытке установить библиотеку, например

> python -m pip install pyaotogui
> python -m pip install BeautifulSoup4

помогите разобраться и победить эту напасть :)

Answer (score 1):

простите за беспокойство, косяк был в том, что выбран не верный интерпритатор

Comment: Вы можете удалить свой вопрос, если он уже не имеет смысла.